# Convergence of series using subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $\sum^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}a_n$ is a convergent series of positive numbers, and $\{a_{n_i}\}^\infty_\mathrm{i=1}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_{n}\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$,
prove that $\sum^\infty_\mathrm{i=1}a_{n_i}$ converges.

I see several places on this site that talk about the convergence of sequences in this context. Specifically, I'm confused why $\sum^\infty_\mathrm{i=1}a_{n_i}$ , a series , must converge given the above information. If this is a simple proof, then that would be great. If the proof relies on some comparison test, what is the logic being used?

Comment: Saying the series converges says the series of partial sums converges. What can you say about the partial sums???

Comment: The partial sum Si is the sum of the first i terms in the sequence. Each partial sum (i, i+1, i+2) will be greater than the last, but by a progressively smaller amount?

Comment: I also note that if a sequence converges, all of it's subsequential limits are the same. (i.e. there is only one subsequential limit) Hence any subsequence of the original sequence converges to the same point. I'm still struggling to apply that back to a series from one of the subsequences.

Comment: that last point isn't all the relevant. Because if $(a_{n_j})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ that does _not_ make the partial sums of $\sum a_{n_j}$ a subsequence of the partial sums of $sum a_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $s_j$ the $j$-th partial sum of $a_{n_i}$ and denote by $t_N$ the $N$-th partial sum of $a_n$. Choose $N(j)$ so that
$$
s_j \le t_{N(j)}
$$
That is, choose $N$ large enough so that all the terms in $s_j$ also appear in $t_{N(j)}$. Since $t_N$ converges, the subsequence $t_{N(j)}$ converges also. Thus passing to the limit as $j \to \infty$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{n_i} = \lim_{j\to\infty} s_{j} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sum a_{n_i}\leq\sum a_n$, because you are adding only some of the terms of $a_n$.

Comment: That's the idea, but writing it this way doesn't really make any sense. The problem is to show that $\sum a_{n_j}$ converges. You really can't refer to $\sum a_{n_j}$ in a proof of **that**, because we don't know that there's any such thing as "$\sum a_{n_j}$" **until** we've shown the series converges!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I tried to write a proof using Cauchy criterion. Does it check out..

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy criterion, there exists $N \in \mathbf{N}$ such that for all $n > m \geq N$, we have

$$|a_m + a_{m + 1} + \ldots + a_{n}| < \epsilon \tag{1}$$

Let $(a_{n_i})$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $(a_n)$.

$$(a_{n_i}) := (a_{n_1},a_{n_2},\ldots)$$

Let $a_{n_j}$ and $a_{n_l}$ be any two terms of the subsequence satisfying $n_l > n_j \geq N$. Then, from (1), it follows that, for all $n_l > n_j \geq N$, we have

$$|a_{n_j} + a_{{n_j}+1} + \ldots + a_{n_l}| < \epsilon$$

Since all numbers on the LHS are positive, we can only leave the terms of the subsequence and drop the remaining terms and write for all $n_l > n_j \geq N$:

$$|a_{n_{j}} + a_{n_{j+1}} + \ldots + a_{n_l}| < |a_{n_j} + a_{n_{j}+1} + \ldots + a_{n_l}| < \epsilon$$

Consequently, by the Cauchy Criterion, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{n_i}$ is convergent.

Comment: the notation $|a_{n_j} + a_{n_k} + \ldots + a_{n_l}|$ makes no sense. If you simply delete that term things are fine

Comment: @David C. Ullrich I'm unsure about which term you think should be deleted. Most of the proof relies on that notation. You are correct that the notation itself is confusing.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I made some edits. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Great..........

Comment: @BobMcdonald By "that term" I meant the $|a_{n_j}+a_{n_k}+\dots +a_{n_l}|$. That's not just "confusing" notation, it's meaningless. And no, the proof doesn't rely on this term; it's been deleted and the resulting proof is just fine.